# Preloading open() for files sourced by tcsh

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh, ld-preload

I am overriding the file open system calls (open, open64, fopen, fopen64, freopen, freopen64) in a dynamic library and setting LD_PRELOAD to point to that library.

Here is a sample script I'm testing this on -

```
#!/bin/tcsh
source testcsh1.csh
source testbash1.sh
```

On RHEL 5.7 (tcsh 6.14.00), the open() called for testcsh1.csh and testbash1.sh is intercepted. However, the intercept (call to the overriding function in dynamic library) does not happen for the following -

1. RHEL 6.6 (tcsh 6.17.00)
2. RHEL 7.1 (tcsh 6.18.01)
3. SLES 11 SP1 (tcsh 6.15.00)
4. CentOS 6.6 (tcsh 6.17.00)

The open() which is not intercepted can be seen using gdb and strace.

Please advise on the possible reasons or the next steps to debug this. Thanks!

Comment: Try set `LD_DEBUG=all`.

Comment: @DaBler It generated over 200k lines of output for me. Any tips please on what specifically I should be looking for?

Comment: I would `grep` the output for lines containing the string `open` or name of your library.

Comment: @DaBler sorry for such a late feedback. Using LD_DEBUG=all gave me detailed information about how the various symbols were resolved. The problematic open syscall (which was not intercepted) was done via an open variant I didn't know about and hence had not overriden yet. Thanks a lot!